# Select multi-line text without overflow the width

Tags: javascript, css

[image]

The up image shows the unwanted red selection out of the yellow area when you select cross lines. I want to select within the yellow part, like the following:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        This is some content... This is a long lonnnnnnng content.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #666;
}

#child {
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: #ff0;
}

::selection {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Do you know how to achieve this?

Run code here: http://jsfiddle.net/3AESf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block;` on `#parent` to solve it

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: In advanced you could also move `padding: 50px;` from `#child` to `#parent`. Than you're selecting only within the `child`-container.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, if `display:inline-block` would not be an option, would be to add

`overflow: hidden;`

to `#parent`. That works too.